# Magento 2 :How to override Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender.php model?

Tags: magento2, model, di.xml

Is their any way we can override Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender.php model in magento 2 module ?

I have created below files

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender" type="Mod\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender" />
</config>


app/code/Mod/Sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php
```

I have added log in

```
protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/prepareTemplate.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('$templateId');
```

but log did not generated.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Any corrections ?

Comment: Do you still need any help?

Answer (score 1):

**`Update`**

Updated the Observer Class

---

If you want to override the model `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender` just to extend the method `prepareTemplate` in order to add or modify email order template variables or change the template id, then its not the recommended approach.

Better observe the event `email_order_set_template_vars_before` and in your observer method add or modify the order email template variables as per your requirement.

Sample code added below

`app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="email_order_set_template_vars_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\OrderEmailSetTemplateVars" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer class - `app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/OrderEmailSetTemplateVars.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order as OrderResource;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class OrderEmailSetTemplateVars extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender implements ObserverInterface 
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;
    
    /**
     * @var Template
     */
    protected $templateContainer;

    
    /**
     * @var PaymentHelper
     */
    protected $paymentHelper;

    /**
     * @var OrderResource
     */
    protected $orderResource;

    /**
     * Global configuration storage.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $globalConfig;

    /**
     * @var Renderer
     */
    protected $addressRenderer;

    /**
     * Application Event Dispatcher
     *
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $eventManager;

    /**
     * @param Template $templateContainer
     * @param OrderIdentity $identityContainer
     * @param Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param Renderer $addressRenderer
     * @param PaymentHelper $paymentHelper
     * @param OrderResource $orderResource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $globalConfig
     * @param ManagerInterface $eventManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template $templateContainer,
        OrderIdentity $identityContainer,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Renderer $addressRenderer,
        PaymentHelper $paymentHelper,
        OrderResource $orderResource,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $globalConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct($templateContainer, $identityContainer, $senderBuilderFactory, $logger, $addressRenderer);
        $this->paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
        $this->orderResource = $orderResource;
        $this->globalConfig = $globalConfig;
        $this->addressRenderer = $addressRenderer;
        $this->identityContainer = $identityContainer;
        $this->logger = $logger ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(LoggerInterface::class);
        $this->templateContainer = $templateContainer;
    }
    

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->logger->debug('Observer '.__CLASS__.' called.');
        $transportObject = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
        
//        $transportObject = $observer->getEvent()->getTransportObject();
        $order = $transportObject->getOrder(); 
        $this->logger->debug('Order Id: ' . $order->getId());
        
        // you can use get this var in your order email template
        $transportObject->setData('test_var','Test Value'); // or $transportObject->getTestVar('Test Value');
        
        // get order's shipping method and set the email template based on that
        $shippingMethod = $order->getShippingMethod();
        $this->logger->debug('Order Shipping Method  ' . $shippingMethod);
        
        if ($this->templateContainer) {
            
            $this->templateContainer->setTemplateOptions($this->getTemplateOptions());

            if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
                $templateId = $this->identityContainer->getGuestTemplateId();
                $customerName = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
            } else {
                $templateId = $this->identityContainer->getTemplateId();
                $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
            }
            
            if ($shippingMethod == 'freeshipping_freeshipping') {
                $templateId = 10; // set your template id here based on the shipping method
            }
            
            $this->templateContainer->setTemplateId($templateId);
            
            $orderEmailTemplateId = $this->templateContainer->getTemplateId();
            
            $this->logger->debug('set order email template id based on shipping method : ' . $orderEmailTemplateId);
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but i need to implement a functionality that checks for shipping method & based on that shipping method i need to use different email template as order confirmation.

Any thoughts on that ? Thanks

Comment: My requirement is to send custom email template based on order shipping method

Comment: @devhs updated the code. it checks the order shipping method and sets the order confirmation email template accordingly.

Comment: Great Thanks, let me check & update.

Comment: I can see a method prepareTemplate() which sets the template id for the order,
Magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php

also same method available in
Magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php

Can you please tell me what's the difference between these two methods & which runs at the end or before event dispatch? Thanks

Comment: $order           = $transportObject->getData('order');

I am getting null over here

Comment: Also getting this error can not access protected property Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender::$templateContainer

Comment: vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php is an abstract class and Magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php extends this abstract class. In your case, you cannot use the observer as well as should not override the Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php. So just follow the approach that i am going to add. Use the updated answer.

Comment: updated the observer class and it can change the order email template based on the shipping method. confirmed it works !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120117/discussion-between-devhs-and-haijerome).

Comment: @devhs sorry, am not available for chat. You can check the answer. I confirmed that it works now.

Comment: Thankyou i will check

Answer (score 0):

We can't rewrite the method of an abstract class, in this case, it is `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender`

Instead of that, we need to find the actual class that is being used, likely it is `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender`

Comment: Yes, is their any way i can implement according to requirement which is to send custom email template based on order shipping method.

Comment: let me check...