# Magento 2 : How to override the abstract class [ sender.php] in custom module

Tags: email-templates, order-email, override-model, send-mail, abstract-class

I create a custom module to send email to customer and admin separately if i try to override the core file in my custom module its shown error .Error come when i override the [ sender.php ] file in my custom module could you please suggest me regarding this so i can proceed forward.

[image]

Comment: Give your code please (OrderSender.php and di.xml)

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting not use Plugin and it little complicated at this method and

Suggesting to use Class rewrite using .

**di.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="Hatrid\OrderConfirmation\Reurite\liagento\Sales" />
</config>
```

> Rewrite class StackExchange\Magento\Rewrite\OrderSender.php

```
<?php
Hatrid\OrderConfirmation\Reurite\liagento;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Sales extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template $templateContainer, 
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $identityContainer, 
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
            \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
            \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $orderResource,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $globalConfig,
            \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     ) {
        parent::__construct($templateContainer, 
                $identityContainer,
                $senderBuilderFactory,
                $logger,
                $addressRenderer,
                $paymentHelper,
                $orderResource,
                $globalConfig,
                $eventManager
                );
                $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
    protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order){

        // your custom code here

    }
}
```

Comment: i want to need of sender.php file to override because this is use abstract class . so what can i do to override the sender.php

Comment: First write your code exactly what you do for override that.............

Answer (score 0):

You can also use event observer for override the sender.php

check this one I think this will more helpful for you

[Magento 2 :How to override Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender.php model?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/331638/magento-2-how-to-override-magento-sales-model-order-email-sender-php-model)